# How to query items that have full match of its children in Child table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables: ParentChild and Child.

ParentChild table has 2 columns PID and CID, where 1 PID can map to multiple CIDs. Child table contains distinct CIDs. The thing is CIDs in Child table doesn't necessarily cover all CIDs in ParentChild table.

Now I want to find all PIDs that each PID has all its CIDs in Child table. Examples:
  P1 has 3 CIDs, if all are in Child table, P1 is selected;
  P2 has 2 CIDs, if not all are in Child table, P2 is not selected.

How do I write query in a clear and performant way?

Comment: show some sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select pc.pid
from parentchild pc left join
     child c
     on pc.cid = c.cid
group by pc.pid
having count(*) = count(c.cid);
```

The last condition checks that all children match.